# @ManagedProperty annotated type returns null

Tags: jsf-2, ejb-3.0, jpa-2.0, glassfish-3

I have this Service bean:

```
@Stateless
public class BookService
{
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="persistentUnit")
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    public BookModel find(Long id) {
       return entityManager.find(BookModel.class, id);
    }
}
```

And the backing bean for the Facelet page is:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "bookBean")
@RequestScoped
public class BookBean implements Serializable
{
    @EJB
    private BookService bookService;

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{param.id}")
    private Long id;

    private DataModel<BookModel> books;
    private BookModel currentBook;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        if (id == null) {
           // UPDATE: Retrieve a list of books.
        } else { 
           // UPDATE: id shouldn't be null here.
           // Get detail info about a book using the id
           currentBook = bookService.find(id);
        }
    }

    public Long getId() {
       return id;
    } 

    public void setId(Long id) {
       this.id = id;
    } 

    public BookModel getCurrentBook() {
       return currentBook;
    }

    public void setCurrentBook(BookModel currentBook) {
       this.currentBook = currentBook;
    }
 }
```

Why is the value of `id` always returns null even though the URL returned as `bookedit.jsf?id=5418` I don't understand this.

Also, I find the `EntityManager#find` method quite restrictive in that it only accept a primary key value as the second parameter. What if I want to pass a [hashed] value instead of the primary key. How can I do this with the `EntityManager#find` method?

P.S. I notice the `EntityManager#find` requirement is the same for both OpenJPA and EclipseLink implementations. Hmm...

Comment: You're trying to use injected value in @PostConstruct. I'm not sure what happens first - @ManagedProperty injection or @PostConstruct. Have you checked it?

Comment: @Osw: `@PostConstruct` runs after all dependency injection, so that part is fine.

Comment: @BalusC: You are correct as per the documentation on DI and `@PostContruct`. Still, I'm not sure why I am getting `null` instead of `5148`. It's very strange!

Comment: Code looks fine. It's likely a typo or some oversight. I'd start debugging the request parameter map inside the constructor/postconstruct. Explore the `ExternalContext#getRequestParameterMap()` to see if the param is there.

Comment: Is it really possible to refer to a parameter by using #{param.id}? Don't you have to bind the parameter to a property of a managedbean and read it from there?

Comment: About the EntityManager question, I think you should open a new separate question for this. But the short answer: use Criterias or a JPQL query.

Comment: @BalusC: I think I know why it does not pick up the id's value because as I can see through testing that the `@PostConstruct` method is only executed once during the life of the bean. What happen if I referenced the same bean - after all, the data are coming from the same table - for generating a list of records (book.xhtml) and for display detail of record (bookview.xhtml)? Can I use the same backing bean to do this? Or, am I wronged in my approach? Note: I have updated my original post with some more info.

Comment: I start to think that it's a bug in your environment. I can't reproduce this with a blank/default JSF 2.0.4 project on Tomcat 7.0.11 nor Glassfish 3.0.1. Don't you have some odd filters/viewhandlers/navigationhandlers/phaselisteners/etc in your environment?

Comment: I started with a clean slate with Glassfish and it seems to work now, somehow, I don't know. My previous Glassfish configuration was using OpenJPA and I had some issues with it. My current configuration uses EclipseLink and it just work. I also got some weird errors regarding Glassfish in Eclipse. For example, every time I changed something within a class, Eclipse would complain I have syntactical errors, which is not true. I'm wondering if the Glassfish 3.1 plugin for Eclipse is broken?

Anyway, sorry guys for wasting your time. Thank you everyone for your valuable contribution and feedback.

Comment: Just for future reference, you may use view parameters for more flexibility: http://java.dzone.com/articles/bookmarkability-jsf-2

Comment: @Victor: Yep, that's another way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried this in one of my managed beans, and it is working.  Here's the relevant code, it's basically the same as yours:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class TestBean {
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.id}")
    private Long prop;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println(prop);
        // prints 1234 if I go to the url with http://localhost/page.jsf?1234
    }

    public Long getProp() {
        return prop;
    }

    public void setProp(Long prop) {
        this.prop = prop;
    }
}
```

I'm running this on glassfish 3.1.1.  The only thought I had is maybe the injected EJB is somehow messing up the request scope in the ManagedBean?